# INNER JOIN with two columns not working properly

Tags: mysql

I have two tables named 'clubs' and 'timetable' in a database. The columns in clubs are club_no, club and stadium. timetable table has four columns: match_no, team_one, team_two and date.

'Match_no' ranges from 1 to 56. 'team_one' and 'team_two' have numbers from 1 to 8. This eight numbers are id's derived from 'club_no' column in the table clubs.

But when I put this query I get zero rows:

```
SELECT * FROM timetable
INNER JOIN clubs ON (
    timetable.team_one=clubs.club_no AND timetable.team_two=clubs.club_no
);
```

What I want is a table with column names like this: Match_no, team_one, team_two and date. But the columns team_one and team_two should be replaced by club names from 'clubs' table using 'club_no' which is unique for each club.

Also, I tried several answers from stackoverflow over this topic but none helped. It always returns 0 rows.

Comment: Your join condition is looking for rows where `team_one`, `team_two`, and `club_no` are all the same!  I'm assuming you have no rows where `team_one=team_two`.

Comment: yes, team_one and team_two are always different. So, can you suggest something. TY.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this in a single JOIN.  Your `ON` clause is looking for rows where *both* `team_one` and `team_two` are equal to `club_no`.  Thus, it's equivalent to `team_one=team_two`, which I'm assuming you don't have.

What you need to do is do a `JOIN` for each team.

```
SELECT timetable.Match_no, timetable.date, club1.club AS team1, club2.club AS team2
FROM timetable
INNER JOIN clubs AS club1 ON timetable.team_one = club1.club_no
INNER JOIN clubs AS club2 ON timetable.team_two = club2.club_no;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Can you explain me how this worked. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: This works because `clubs` just acts as a "lookup table" for the two teams in the `timetable`.  MySQL don't mind how many times you JOIN a table (you can even join a table to itself), just as long as they each have unique aliases.  Each team (`team_one` and `team_two`) have different IDs, so they need to each be joined on their own.  I hope that explains it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
SELECT C1.club, C2.club, T.Match_no, T.Date FROM timetable T 
INNER JOIN clubs C1 ON C1.club_no = T.team_one
INNER JOIN clubs C2 ON C2.club_no = T.team_two
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
select * from timetable
  inner join clubs on (timetable.team_once = clubs.club_no or timetable.team_two=clubs.club_no)
```

Answer (score 1):

try changing the AND to OR

```
SELECT * FROM timetable t
JOIN clubs c ON t.team_one=c.club_no OR t.team_two=c.club_no;
```

alternatively you can also join for each team which is probably the better solution

```
SELECT t.time, c.match_no, c.team_one, c1.team_two
FROM timetable t
JOIN clubs c ON t.team_one=c.club_no
JOIN clubs c1 ON t.team_two=c1.club_no
```

**NOTE** i added aliases for your tables as its easier to read the columns when you have a short table name

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution using nested joins. This works but I feel it's not the most optimized solution.

```
select m_no, team1, clubs.club, date FROM 
    ( select timetable.match_no as m_no, clubs.club as team1, timetable.team_two as team2, timetable.date as date 
       FROM timetable INNER JOIN clubs ON timetable.team_one = clubs.club_no) T 
    INNER JOIN clubs ON T.team2=clubs.club_no
```